# DVD drives keep failing

Tags: sata, dvd

I built a new PC for myself about a year ago, i5, Asus MB, corsair power supply, MSI Nvidia GPU. I forget the full specs (I can post them if someone thinks they might be relevant). In that year I've gone through two DVD drives. Again I forget the exact specs but they're just simple SATA ROM drives for ripping DVDs. They were about $20 each, and I'm about to shell out for a third. The reason is that they seem to just stop working after a time. At first they work perfectly, but eventually they stop. The drive is still recognized by the OS (dual-boot Kubuntu & Win 7), and when I put in a DVD it can read the disc title. But as it tries to play, or scan chapters it tries and tries, but never managed to succeed anymore. This is true of both OS's. And in only talking maybe three or four DVD rips this last time before failing, so it's not just wearing out through use.

I'm beginning to wonder if the power supply is at fault. Could this be the result of low or inconsistent power to the drive? Or can anyone suggest anything else? Am I just getting cheap drives? That seems to be the going rate for them these days.

Any ideas or suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you suspect the power supply, you should investigate that, if you can use different power cables and SATA cables you should do that.  If you are buying the same brand, get a different brand this third time.

Comment: I'll try swapping out the cables. That sounds like the simplest first step.

Comment: Could it be grunge on the optics? Try a CD/DVD cleaner disk, and be sure dirt is not getting pulled in, either through the fan(s) or on a DVD.

Comment: Ah! Even better idea!  I'll definitely try cleaning the drive first.  And entirely plausible considering the amount of hair my cat produces.